# Buffered polygon is not as expected QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I used the Buffer tool in QGIS (-10 m, all other parameters as default) on the red polygon; the result is the orange polygon.

I drew a blue arrow where it seemed that the buffer did not work well. I would expect this area to be also "buffered in".

Polygon:

[image]

Polygon and buffer

[image]

I use QGIS version 3.22.16-Białowieża.

Here is my polygon:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32635" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "polygon_id": 22 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 539760.0, 4284740.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539750.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539750.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539740.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539740.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539730.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539730.0, 4284650.0 ], [ 539740.0, 4284650.0 ], [ 539740.0, 4284640.0 ], [ 539730.0, 4284640.0 ], [ 539730.0, 4284630.0 ], [ 539750.0, 4284630.0 ], [ 539750.0, 4284610.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284610.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284600.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284600.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284590.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284590.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284580.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284580.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284590.0 ], [ 539800.0, 4284590.0 ], [ 539800.0, 4284630.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284630.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284640.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284640.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539850.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539850.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539880.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539880.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539860.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539860.0, 4284700.0 ], [ 539850.0, 4284700.0 ], [ 539850.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539840.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539840.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284740.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284740.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284730.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284730.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284740.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284740.0 ] ], [ [ 539780.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284710.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284710.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284720.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284720.0 ] ], [ [ 539760.0, 4284710.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284700.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284700.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284710.0 ], [ 539760.0, 4284710.0 ] ], [ [ 539770.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284670.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539780.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539770.0, 4284690.0 ] ], [ [ 539810.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284680.0 ], [ 539820.0, 4284690.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284690.0 ] ], [ [ 539790.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284650.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284650.0 ], [ 539810.0, 4284660.0 ], [ 539790.0, 4284660.0 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: You could try applying a tiny positive buffer first (something like 1cm) and then your negative buffer, with the extra 1cm added.

Comment: I agree with you. OpenJUMP handles that corner as you expect. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6soB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6soB.png)

Comment: Hi, I tried, and the 1 cm buffer "fills up" the hole near my blue error, then the -10 m buffer does not go "deep" enough as expected, I'll add a screenshot of the polygon without the buffer.

Comment: I tried also PostGIS with `ST_Buffer(geom,-10)` and it gives the same result than QGIS. Probably because they are both using the GEOS library. However, GEOS is based on JTS that OpenJUMP is using so I would have thought similar result from that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source geometry is invalid. There is a self-intersection at the place that you pointed because of missing vertex. I had to correct the geometry manually because "make valid" filled the empty area within the loop.

[image]

With a corrected geometry the buffer looks like this

[image]

Comment: You can use the clean function from GRASS gis that is available in Qgis via processing. In the processing toolbox you may use v.clean with the "break" cleaning tool. It will solve self intersections by adding nodes.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it.

Comment: @nepluisse - do you happen to know if the `v.clean` function also exist in Python packages such as `shapely`  /  `fiona`  /  `geopandas`?